# Why is this regex not working?

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex that looks like `\D*(\d*).*`. What it is meant to do is get the first number it can find and store it in the first capture group. However, when I feed it a string like `testing123`, it does not match it! This has been confusing me for a while; why will it not match?

Java code:

```
String s = "testing123"
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\D*(\\d*).*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
//m did not match anything
```

Comment: What programming language are you attempting to use this regex in (Java? Perl? Javascript?), and what's the full line of code that it appears in?

Comment: "\d" only matches alpha chars

Comment: @felipsmartins `\d` is digits, right? and `\D` is non-digits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are using the `Matcher` object incorrectly: calling

```
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

prints `123`

([link to ideone](http://ideone.com/9Ucvjf)).

Comment: Hrm. Something was wrong with my code, I guess. Thanks, I'll accept when SO lets me!

Comment: @PicklishDoorknob, in the future you can also use http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html to validate your regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

#### Simplify Your Regex

Your expression is:

> \D*(\d*).*

This means:

1. Zero or more characters except for digits...
2. Followed by zero or more digits...
3. Followed by zero or more characters.

Aside from any syntax issues, this seems like an unnecessary complication. To match digits on a line, why not just capture the digits? For example:

```
\d+
```

Or, if you want to ensure that you have only digits at the end of a word boundary, something like:

```
\d+\b
```

will work just fine with any PCRE-compatible engine. In Java, this consistently places "123" into `group(0)` without the need for capturing sub-expressions.

Comment: IIRC Java patterns are always anchored to the beginning and end of the string to match, hence the need for the leading `\D*` and trailing `.*`, so your simplification would actually break his code.

Comment: @vladr "It Works for Me." Try it yourself using a string like "foo testing123 bar" if you like; according to http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html, `group(0)` is always correctly set to "123" with the minimal regex.

Comment: good, but `matches()` returns `false` -- this is the subtlety that I remembered existed there.